# Is agreeing to contact my referee considered accepting offer letter?

Tags: united-kingdom, lecturer

I had accepted an oral offer for lecturer position in UK. I had the offer letter, with question if it is ok to contact my referee? I answered yes and I informed the HR that I had couple of questions before approving the offer. They answered but I did not say yes to offer as I had meeting with HoD to discuss my salary and start-up package

I was surprised that I received reply that I already accepted my offer. It is hard to negotiate at this point

What should I do? I need this job, should I inform them of this confusion and ask for clarification?

Comment: This is hard to understand. Did you give a verbal acceptance? That can be considered binding in some places, though I don't know if it is so in the UK.

Comment: I had accepted the oral offer but not offer letter

Comment: That might be a distinction without meaning.

Comment: I'm also confused by the fact that they still want to contact referees if they are already under the impression that the deal had been done. Clearly, for you to accept an offer means that they have made you a binding offer. In that case, what's the point of asking referees?

Comment: Yes, I agree on this, the offer letter I was sent is conditional offer on receiving the pre-employment check, will be unconditional.

Comment: I think you need to show someone smart with UK specific knowledge emails that were sent. Today. It may be that they read “yes contact my referee” as “yes to the offer” because of some sentence structure issue or similar. Then craft a very clear reply that your oral acceptance was conditional on an acceptable negotiation of the offer details.

Comment: I did this and she recommended to contact HR for clarification